# Setting Date & Time via SMS or any other non -NTP protocol based routines

Tags: date, datetime, time, sms, ntp

I'm stuck with the problem that NTP time synchronsation does not work via UMTS/GPRS connections due to Telecom blocked lower port numbers (to a mobile Raspberry Pi).

One solution (1) could be to do it "manually" by SMS (frequently on request).

Another solution(2) could be to request a time update from (my) managed server in the cloud by bash routines (of course not via NTP ... any other routines to recommend? - any help is appreciated ...)

A third solution(3) could be to establish a VPN channel to the cloud server and get the time from this server (but too complicated for me right now)

Looking for solution (1) - the SMS raw-format looks like this:

```
From: 4yzzzxxxxxxxx

From_TOA: 91 international, ISDN/telephone

From_SMSC: 491710760000

Sent: 16-01-09 11:03:10

Received: 16-01-09 11:03:25

Subject: GSM1

Modem: GSM1

IMSI: 2423834284738

Report: no

Alphabet: ISO

Length: 7

SMS Message Body
```

I am interested in the 4th line (**Sent: 16-01-09 11:03:10**) of the above SMS raw message content, which shows the sender time (network time).

I would be happy to extract this time and assign it to the bash "date" via "set date ...." bash coding.

Unfortunately (as a linux beginner) I am not familar with awk, sed or regex at all to do the format transition from the "16-01-09 11:03:10" format to the linux default "Di 2. Jan 05:00:03 CET 2016" format.

Could somebody guide me please, how to extract the date in line 4 in the above message file and synchronize it with the linux "date" format by bash coding?

A code sniplet would be pretty much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For extracting the relevant line and setting the date you could use the following commandline (executed as root and getting piped the text as shown above):

```
awk '/^Sent:/ { printf "%s%s%s%s%s%s\n",substr($2,4,2),substr($2,7,2),substr($3,1,2),substr($3,4,2),20,substr($2,1,2) ; }' | xargs date
```

Hoever, you should be aware that this (and also any approach that is simply reading a remote clock (your solutions 1 and 2) and setting that as local time) 
will suffer from unpredictable network delay. If it is OK to you to be systematically off  (but within some milliseconds to seconds) the you may follow that path.

NTP would provide you with functionality of compensating network delay (among other beneficial properties). So, using a tunnelled connection (solution 3) would definitely be a better approach.

You might also consider a solution 4:

Purchasing a reference clock (DCF77 modules are rather cheap) and connect it to your Raspberry Pi.
(There might already be some examples for such modules from that community.)
USB based modules are also available but tend to be a bit more expensive.
(DCF77 will work inside Europe only, but you mentioned "CET" so it might be OK for you.)